# Given a string move to index of desired characters

Tags: python

With reference to [single-row-keyboard](https://leetcode.com/contest/biweekly-contest-7/problems/single-row-keyboard/).

The problem says:

> Given a string keyboard of length 26 indicating the layout of the
>   keyboard (indexed from 0 to 25), initially your finger is at index 0.
>   To type a character, you have to move your finger to the index of the
>   desired character. The time taken to move your finger from index i to
>   index j is |i - j|.

```
Input: keyboard = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", word = "cba"
Output: 4
Explanation: The index moves from 0 to 2 to write 'c' then to 1 to write 'b' then to 0 again to write 'a'.
Total time = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4.
```

This is a fairly simple problem which should not take much time. So I attempted the below solution for it.

```
def key_front(num, k, word, keyboard):
    for x in range(k):
        if word[num] == keyboard[x]:
            return x
    return 0

def calculateTime(keyboard, word):
    k = len(keyboard)
    count = 0
    i = 0
    w = len(word)
    diff = 0
    while i < w:
        front = 0
        front = key_front(i, k, word, keyboard)
        print(front,diff,word[i],count)
        if word[i] == word[i-1]:
            diff = 0
        diff = abs(front-diff)
        count += diff
        i = i + 1
    return count
```

The point that I am using recusrion here is because there might be a case where each chareacter can appear multiple times in sequential order always.
My code fails for the below test case when such scenario occurs:

```
keyboard="pyevcountbgjklxfqwimrdhazs"
word="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"
Output = 66042
```

Comment: What about "string keyboard of length 26"?

Comment: You say you're using recursion, but I don't see any recursive functions here. Is there more code in your program than what you've shown us? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Kevin see this loop `while hashmap[word[i]]`. I used recursion only if the count of alphabet is greater than 0

Comment: If you're saying "my function is recursive because it has a while loop in it", that's not what recursion is. A function is recursive if it calls itself. `calculateTime` never calls `calculateTime`, so it isn't recursive.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist yes they were. Thats not part of the original question but its more like a followup question. Assume the characters are repeated sequentially.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist yes

Comment: @Kevin yes you are correct. Sorry my bad. Because I was calling key_front repeatedly I thought its recursion. Thanks for correcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code a little bit, but only to the point that it is giving correct result. If you want to optimize your code, @hiro protagonist's answer is a pretty good example to start with.

```
# this function is working fine
def key_front(num, k, word, keyboard):
    for x in range(k):
        if word[num] == keyboard[x]:
            return x
    return 0

def calculateTime(keyboard, word):
    k = len(keyboard)
    count = 0
    i = 0
    w = len(word)
    diff = 0
    # I've added a new variable here to store "your finger's" previous position:
    prev_front = 0
    while i < w:
        # there is no need to initialize "front" here
        front = key_front(i, k, word, keyboard)
        print(front,diff,word[i],count)
        #if word[i] == word[i-1], front and prev_front would be the same, resulting diff == 0

        diff = front - prev_front
        # assigning our new variable prev_front
        prev_front = front
        # diff might be negative so we only need it's absolute value
        count += abs(diff)
        i = i + 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work:

```
keyboard = "pyevcountbgjklxfqwimrdhazs"
word = "gxafwhexxykisc...jebxjfrfoxatxhi"

keys = {char: index for index, char in enumerate(keyboard)}

index = 0
s = 0
for char in word:
    i = keys[char]
    s += abs(index - i)
    index = i
print(s)  # 66042
```

i create the look-up table `keys` for the keyboard first, then i loop over the `char`acters of your `word`, update the `index` i currently am and sum the `abs`olute difference between the new ald the old `index` in the running sum `s`.

---

in your solution `diff` is always assigned to `0` and will never be any other value: you only handle the case where the current and the previous letters are the same.

also you do not seem to keep the current index you are at.

Comment: I got this. But can you suggest what am I doing wrong

Comment: See now its not like that. `front` is the character we are looking for and `diff` is the index of previous character.

Comment: yes, I have. Using Dict is fine. But I am still trying to find how I can modify my solution.Thanks for your help